# Is it possible to add two multi-dimensional arrays together to a third multi-dimensional array

Tags: c++, arrays, multidimensional-array

I am attempting to add two multi-dimensional arrays together into a third array without much success.The first two arrays I created have values and I am unsure of exactly how to add multi-dimensional array a to multi-dimensional array b hand have the value place properly in mult-directional array c. Below is what I started to come up.

Thanks in advance for your time and skills.

```
int main()
{
int a[2] [3] = 
{
    { 16, 18, 23 },
    { 54, 91, 11 }
};

int b[2][3] =
{
        { 14, 52, 77 },
        { 16, 19, 59 }
};

int c[2][3];

for (int rows = 0; rows < 2; rows++)
{
    for (int columns = 0; columns < 3; columns++)
    {
        c[rows][columns] = b[rows][columns] + a[rows][columns];
    }
}
_getch();
return 0;

}
```

Comment: What exactly is your question? Your code works just fine and does exactly what you've described.

Comment: You are right. It looks like when I went to output my code the first time I stuck my for loop in the wrong spot, it is working now. Should I delete this thread or leave it for reference for others?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way to do it shorter: Flatten the pointers and use `transform`.

```
int c[2][3];
std::transform( *a, *std::end(a), *b, *c, std::plus<int>() ); // Or plus<> since C++14
```

Comment: Thanks for the advice, this is good to know and a lot shorter.